# What is the difference between child: and children: property in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

What is the difference between child: and children: property in Flutter?

I started studying flutter for 2 weeks from Flutter official documentation and I don't find it as easy as studying Android.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`child` takes a single widget

```
child: Text('foo')
```

`children` takes a list of widgets

```
children: <Widget>[Text('foo'), Text('bar')]
```

Comment: Thank you. Günter Zöchbauer. It is really a short to the point answer. Can u please show me some links for good tutorials for Flutter?

Comment: Not sure what you would consider good tutorials. A good starting point is https://flutter.io/ https://github.com/Solido/awesome-flutter might help as well.

Comment: Also the entries linked from https://flutter.io/docs/reference/tutorials and https://flutter.io/docs/codelabs are also good.

Comment: Clear and concise. Thanks.

Comment: @ThitSarNL I recently started learning flutter and I think a very practical resource for learning Flutter is "Flutter Apprentice By Vincenzo Guzzi, Kevin D Moore, Vincent Ngo and Michael Katz" book. [Link for book](https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/flutter-apprentice)